# Can I add a MapPolygon to MapLayer in windows phone8 map control?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, maps

I want to add a mappolygon to maplayer in windows phone 8 map control.Now I am able to add mappolygon as map element but it will trigger resolved completed event repeatedly.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: what happens when you try using MapLayer ? to be honest it looks that all my codes are only having markers added with MapLayer, and all polystuff has been added directly to the map.

Comment: No, you can't add a `MapPolygon` to a `MapLayer`. A `MapLayer` operates only on `MapOverlays` as shown in the documentation below... If you can describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail, I might be able to help you find a solution! :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.maplayer(v=vs.105).aspx